# Meaning of addObject in springMVC

Tags: spring, jsp

I am developing a web service using Spring MVC. When I referred to some examples on serving JSP pages in Controller I came across the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
    mav.addObject("login", new Login());
    return mav;
}
```

Can someone tell me the reason for using `addObject` here. I hope "login" refers to the JSP page `login.jsp`. If so, what does `new Login()` refers to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
```

"login" indeed refers to the name of the JSP page. Returning this `ModelAndView` will direct the user to `login.jsp`.

```
mav.addObject("login", new Login());
```

adds an attribute to the `Model` in `ModelAndView`. This means you can access the `Login` object in your JSP page by accessing it through the attribute name "login", e.g. `${login}`.

Comment: I am doing a project on displaying telephone extensions of all the employees in my organisation. I have an excel sheet with all the details. Can you say whether I need to have addObject since I have to insert the values from the excel sheet and not manually. In this case if I want to read the JSP page in my controller what would be the code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. However, as this is a completely new question, I suggest you to open another question.